# create a link with parameters, but show param only if condition occurs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I create a link_to and have a certain param to be in the url only if some condition occurs?

For example, I want to have someurl.com/1111?foo=clown

But the foo should be there only if a condition is true.

If not, it should be just:
someurl.com/1111

Comment: if ( condition ) do smth...

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= link_to 'My Link', your_path(:foo => ("clown" if your_condition)) %>
```

In this exemple, `:param` equals to `"clown"` if `your_condition` is true, else `:param` is `nil` and if the param is nil, Ruby don't consider there is a parameter and ignore it.

Comment: Another way ... <%= link_to 'My Link', your_path(:foo => (your_condition ? "clown" : nil)) %>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple condition like this could work.

```
if (myCondition)
  link_to :myPage, myVariable: var
else
  link_to :myPage
end
```